# why this abap call dialog statement is valid?

Tags: abap

I found an abap statement like this

```
CALL DIALOG 'RF_TABELLE_030'
    EXPORTING T020-AKTYP MSMOD IMP-GRUPP FROM 'BIL'
    IMP-KTOSL FROM 'BIL'
    IMPORTING MSGNR TBSPR TDDAT-CCLASS.
```

I can't find the matching syntax of it from the latest abap keyword document. I guess it might be valid in older abap release(for example, 620), but I can't find the document (the earliest I can find is for 731). please help! many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the documentation of `CALL DIALOG` in the Obsolete Calls section. It is a valid (but deprecated) statement.

[CALL DIALOG AS ABAP Release 756](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapcall_dialog.htm)

Edit:

every actual parameter is assigned to a single formal parameter.

A special case is when formal parameter have the exact name of the actual parameter (see [Addition 3 - Hint](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapcall_dialog.htm#!ABAP_ADDITION_3@3@).

In this case - and if outside of classes - you can omit the `FROM p1` part in `EXPORTING p1 FROM p1` so it becomes `EXPORTING p1`

Your code:

```
CALL DIALOG 'RF_TABELLE_030'
    EXPORTING T020-AKTYP MSMOD IMP-GRUPP FROM 'BIL'
    IMP-KTOSL FROM 'BIL'
    IMPORTING MSGNR TBSPR TDDAT-CCLASS.
```

is the contracted form for

```
CALL DIALOG 'RF_TABELLE_030'
    EXPORTING T020-AKTYP   FROM T020-AKTYP
              MSMOD        FROM MSMOD
              IMP-GRUPP    FROM 'BIL'
              IMP-KTOSL    FROM 'BIL'
    IMPORTING MSGNR        TO   MSGNR
              TBSPR        TO   TBSPR 
              TDDAT-CCLASS TO   TDDAT-CCLASS.
```

Comment: the syntax show that formal parameter and actual parameter have one-to-one relation. but in my example code, the relation is many-to-one, that is , one actual parameter can map to many formal parameters (```T020-AKTYP MSMOD IMP-GRUPP FROM 'BIL'```), which confused me.

Comment: I've added an explanation about how the parameters mapping works

Comment: thank you. I apologize for my lazy. the hint part of the document have stated it clearly.

Comment: @Sandra Rossi: thanks for correcting the typos, but `EXPORTING p1 FROM a1` was correct. See [ABAP doc Addition 3](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapcall_dialog.htm#!ABAP_ADDITION_3@3@)

Comment: @manuel_b You said previously `you can omit the FROM p1 part; so EXPORTING p1 FROM a1 becomes EXPORTING p1`. I'm sorry but it's wrong. Maybe I don't understand what you mean. `EXPORTING p1` is only equivalent to `EXPORTING p1 FROM p1`.

Comment: I just cited the syntax in abap help Addition 3 where they say `... EXPORTING p1 FROM a1 p2 FROM a2 ...`. But yes it is correct to omit the `FROM a1` part, not `FROM p1`.